# Pipeline doesn't seem to have any effect in Bash

Tags: python, bash

Anyone can explain me why this

```
python -V | awk '{print $2}'
```

returns this

```
Python 2.7.5
```

instead of

```
2.7.5
```

What to do to return only the version number without "Python " ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you run

```
python -V >/dev/null
```

you will notice that you still get output! Apparently, `python -V` prints its output to stderr, not to stdout.

In a bourne-like shell, this should work:

```
python -V 2>&1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Nice catch. It turns out, this applies to Python 2 only, Python 3 uses stdout.

Comment: @bereal: Many years of Un*x experience have tought me, that when my filters just refuse to filter, it's usually because I'm filtering the wrong stream. :)

Comment: @bereal: And that's a nice meta-catch by the way; I hadn't even noticed I was testing with Python 2!

Comment: @Ture Your printing versions of python and don't notice your testing with 2? 

Comment: @Nearoo: I suppose I was just looking at the shape of the output, not the actual contents! :)

Answer (score 5):

How about using pure python command itself(I need to format it with dots in between though)

```
python -c 'import sys; print sys.version_info[0],sys.version_info[1],sys.version_info[2]'
```

OR as per Chris's comment use:

```
python -c 'import sys; print(".".join(map(str, sys.version_info[:3])))'
```

Comment: Arguably, this is the right way to do it. It's kind of silly that it takes so much more typing to do it the right way...

Comment: @TurePålsson can be shortened `python -c 'import sys; print(".".join(map(str, sys.version_info[:3])))'`

Comment: @Chris_Rands, Thank you Chris for letting know, I added this in solution now, cheers.

Comment: ++ for using `sys.version_info`